# Android HttpUrlConnection returns a 400 instead of a 404 for non-existent resource

Tags: android, http

The classic code:

```
    String url = "http://arealdomain.com/realfolder/nonexistent.html";
    BufferedReader reader = null;
    BufferedWriter writer = null;
    HttpURLConnection connection = null;


    try{
        URL urlObject = new URL(url);
        connection = (HttpURLConnection)urlObject.openConnection();
        connection.setRequestMethod("GET");

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream(), "UTF-8"));

        String line;
        while((line = reader.readLine()) != null){
            sb.append(line);
        }

    } catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();

        if (connection != null){
            try {
                int status = connection.getResponseCode();

            } catch (IOException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        return null;
    }
    finally{
        if (reader != null) {
            try {
                reader.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return null;
            }
        }

        if (writer != null){
            try {
                writer.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return null;
            }
        }

        if (connection != null){
            connection.disconnect();
        }
    }
```

When I run that bogus URL in a browser, I get the expected 404. However, in the catch block, line `int status = connection.getResponseCode();` That status ends up being a 400.

When I access a resource that requires authorization and I don't provide it, I do get the expected 401.

I really need to let the user know whether their request as invalid (400) vs. if they're requesting something that doesn't or no longer exists (404).

Why does Android not give me a 404 but instead a 400 when I make an HTTP call to something that doesn't exist?

**UPDATE**
The above "phenomenon" happens with an emulator. I'm using Android Studio, HAXM stuff. When I tried this out on a different machine with a real device, I got the expected 404. Strange.

Comment: Do your server logs give you any clues? After all, *Android* is not the one giving you the 400 response. The server is.

Comment: The exception caught is actually a FileNotFoundException. I don't see anything in logcat. I'm running the same bogus URL in Fiddler and I'm getting the 404 I'm expecting.